# Simulating a function with no closed form solution

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, list-manipulation, simulation

So I am trying to simulate a function in 3d. Suppose our function looks like this:

```
f=k*r*a
```

I am interested in simulating the numerical values of k when r is between 0 and 1 and a is between 1 and 5 and f=0.

I think the table should look something like this but it does not work.

```
NSolve[Flatten[Table[k*r*a == 0, {r, 0, 1, 0.01}, {a, 1, 5, 0.05}]]]
```

But even if this works, I think it loses the coordinates of r and a so I won't be able to plot it. Any suggestions?

Comment: `ContourPlot3D[k*r*a==0, {k,-1,1}, {r, 0, 1, 0.01}, {a, 1, 5, 0.05}]`?

Comment: @Alx Oh wow that works, much simpler than what I was trying to do.